# MongoDb Distinct with query C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to use the `db.collection.distinct(field, query)` command, documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). I am trying to call this with the C# driver, documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/).

Currently I am using the code:

```
_repository.Search(item.searchCriteria).Select(i => i.messageId).Distinct().ToList()
```

where messageId is a string and the Search function does:

```
//Create search accross all properties of type.
public IQueryable<SearchType> Search(SearchType entity)
    {
        Type entityType = entity.GetType();
        var propertiesToSearch = entityType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        query = _collection.AsQueryable();
        query = query.WhereAnd(
            query.ElementType,
            propertiesToSearch.Select(p => new SearchCriteria()
                {
                    Column = p.Name,
                    Value = p.GetValue(entity),
                    Operation = WhereOperation.Equal
                }).ToArray());
        return query;
    }
```

So this should get converted to:

```
db.collection.distinct("messageId", { $and: [ { prop1: "" }, { prop2: "" } ]  })
```

I am getting the following error when this is run though:

"Distinct is only supported for a single field. Projections used with Distinct must resolve to a single field in the document."

I am using Mongo 2.4.9 and the official C# driver 1.8.3

Comment: did you try aggregate/group. that should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried trying without your `search` function experimentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.distinct()` method is an older implementation that is more of a convenience method wrapping mapReduce. For anything more involved that simple operations you should use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

So the shell equivalent:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "$and": [ { "prop1": "" }, { "prop2": "" } ] } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$messageId" } }  
])
```

The documents are just formed as a chain of BSON documents. There are various examples [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c/).

Comment: @Andrew does the change here better suit your purpose? You really should be using aggregate here. Which is the point.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to achieve :)

Comment: @NeilLunn The `distinct` command pre-dates the Aggregation Framework .. however it is implemented in C++ and unrelated to MapReduce (ref: [db/commands/distinct.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/db/commands/distinct.cpp)). The `distinct()` helper in the shell is a wrapper for the [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) command.