# Find distinct value of one field in a period

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a table (detecc) with these fields:

```
 uname   string
 door    string
 dt      double (seconds since 1/1/1970)
```

I have this query that works well:

```
double dt1= SeconsdSince1970(DateTime.Now);
double dt0= dt1 - 3600;
var doorSearch = new string[] { "D1", "D2" };
System.Int32 cNow = (from d in detecc
                     where doorSearch.Contains(d.door) &&
                     (d.dt >= dt0 && d.dt <= dt1)
                     select d.uname).Distinct().Count();
```

But if I want to retrieve the users (uname), I get all records (duplicates):

```
double dt1= SeconsdSince1970(DateTime.Now);
double dt0= dt1 - 3600;
var doorSearch = new string[] { "D1", "D2" };
var lisUname = (from d in detecc
                     where doorSearch.Contains(d.door) &&
                     (d.dt >= dt0 && d.dt <= dt1)
                     select d.uname).Distinct();
```

How can I get distinct usernames?

Comment: It should not be possible for `lisUname` to contain duplicate values after that code executes.

Comment: You tagged mongodb is detecc a mongodb collection? or is it an c# poco object? Because if it is a mongodb collection your linq statements are converted to mongodb statements which might work differently.

Comment: Excusme, excusme, excusme, ...  i have: select new Consult {uname = d.uname}).Distinct();  I will try without new Consult...

Comment: YES! it go well. Thank you very much. Now i must conver var to List<>.

Answer (score 3):

#### If you are working with mongodb collections try this

```
// .ToList() converts to poco list
var lisUname = (from d in detecc
                     where doorSearch.Contains(d.door) &&
                     (d.dt >= dt0 && d.dt <= dt1)
                     select d.uname).ToList();

// distinct is now executed in c# context rather mongodb context
var distinctList = lisUname.Distinct();
```

#### A cleaner syntax

```
var list = detecc
    .Where(d => doorSearch.Contains(d.door) && (d.dt >= dt0 && d.dt <= dt1)
    .Select(x => x.uname)
    .ToList();
```

#### Performance

> Note: .Select will always end your query and pass all data (complete documents) to native code. So you get back the complete data from server and your code then is selecting your desired fields. If you want to pull only requested fields another mongodb query approach is required.
>
> [Refer to Documentation on Linq driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)

**For better performance regarding distinct use:**

```
var list = detecc
    .Where(d => doorSearch.Contains(d.door) && (d.dt >= dt0 && d.dt <= dt1)
    .Distinct() // that way distinct is executed on server side
    .ToList();
```

#### Why chaining .Count() with mongodb does not work

> .Count() is meant to be used seperately with own parameters.
>   Refer to this article [Why the MongoDB Count Property Returns All Records](http://inspectorit.com/tips-tricks/why-the-mongodb-count-property-returns-all-records/)

```
// Example
int userCount = db.GetCollection("detecc")
        .Count(Query.EQ("uname", searchedUName));
```

#### A more performant approach with aggregation

For a more performant approach use mongodb aggretation like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "$and": [ { "prop1": "" }, { "prop2": "" } ] } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$messageId" } }  
])
```

> Please refer to this answer: [MongoDb Distinct with query C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598750/mongodb-distinct-with-query-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: That forces the entire collection to be read into memory though. As the set becomes larger this solution will not scale well at all.